# Result View adaptive card Image Action.OpenUrl not working in SharePoint Vertical

Tags: sharepoint-online, adaptive-cards, microsoft-search

i hope the title is self explanatory. I have custom search result (ExternalItem) defined in Microsoft Search Api. I'm retrieving those results in SharePoint Search page: /_layouts/15/search.aspx/

The adaptive card part looks like this:

```
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "url": "${image}",
                            "altText": "Result logo",
                            "size": "Medium",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Right",
                            "selectAction": {
                                "url": "${URL}",
                                "title": "${Title}",
                                "type": "Action.OpenUrl"
                            }
                        }
```

And rendered results doesn't respect Action.OpenUrl on image. It doesn't work also for static URL.